# Exactly same size for all screens physically in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, mobile

[image]

how is it possible that dimensions of any object physically same size on all screens?

Comment: Like...exactly?  Or just approximately?  For the latter, just use `dp` for your measurements.

Comment: That's the point of using dp in height and width

Answer (score 0):

From the android developer's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities):

> To preserve the visible size of your UI on screens with different
>   densities, you must design your UI using density-independent pixels
>   (dp) as your unit of measurement. One dp is a virtual pixel unit
>   that's roughly equal to one pixel on a medium-density screen (160dpi;
>   the "baseline" density). Android translates this value to the
>   appropriate number of real pixels for each other density.
>
> For example, consider the two devices in figure 1. If you were to
>   define a view to be "100px" wide, it will appear much larger on the
>   device on the left. So you must instead use "100dp" to ensure it
>   appears the same size on both screens.

So, what you are trying to achieve is possible using `dp` as the unit for the height and width properties of the object.